# jQuery toggle() issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I am using a script from this discussion: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/14711/14649

It works great, but when I select a different radio input, the original box doesn't toggle off (bad), but the new box does appear (good). This happens for any additional boxes I add.

jQuery is not my thing, and I have been researching around with no luck! Here is my code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#feature_box').hide();
        $('#standard_lead').hide();             

        // one box
        $('#value_feature_box').is(':checked') ? $("#feature_box").show() : $("#feature_box").hide();
        $('#value_feature_box').click(function() {
            $("#feature_box").toggle(this.checked);
        });

        // second box
        $('#value_standard_lead').is(':checked') ? $("#standard_lead").show() : $("#standard_lead").hide();
        $('#value_standard_lead').click(function() {
            $("#standard_lead").toggle(this.checked);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML also?

Comment: Can you add your markup, what is `feature_box` ? is it a div ? This code can be modularized using classes instead of id's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the other box doesn't disappear is because you didn't tell it to!

```
$('#value_feature_box').click(function() {
    $("#feature_box").toggle(this.checked);
});
```

This says to toggle the visibility of #feature_box, when you click on #value_feature_box. If #value_feature_box is not a checkbox, then change the inner code to `$("#feature_box").toggle();`. If you want something to disappear as well, then tell it to:

```
$('#value_feature_box').click(function() {
    $("#feature_box").toggle();
    $("#standard_lead").toggle();
});
```

The value on the inside of the toggle() parentheses is telling it to either appear or disappear(true or false).

Comment: Thank you for your input. This was the solution I did come up with, but it was pretty clunky as I am going to have about 10 boxes, and I feel like using `$("#box_id").toggle();` could get tedious... so I am assigning as class to each box to streamline it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are toggling only one box on click - you need to toggle both, see this jsFiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/Gr8Jq/

With this (and similar for the other box):

```
    $('#value_feature_box').click(function() {
        $("#feature_box").toggle(this.checked);
    });
```

you are basically saying - when clicked (so `this.checked` will always be true), toggle the element. From the docs:

- http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

you are using the version of toggle that has showOrHide parameter and always passing true, so always showing and only the box that was clicked on.

Comment: Thank you for your input. This was the solution I did come up with, but it was pretty clunky as I am going to have about 10 boxes, and I feel like using `$("#box_id").toggle();` could get tedious... so I am assigning as class to each box to streamline it. Thanks!